# Chart JS will not re-render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I'm having trouble getting my Chart from Chart.js to update. I'm using React so it should re-render every time I modify my state, however it is not behaving the way I would like.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { chartData } from './Search.js';
import { xLabels } from './Search.js';
import { allEpsData } from './Search.js';

let chartDataSeason = [];
let xLabelsSeason = [];


export class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectValue: '',
      seasonSelected: false,
      chartIt: {
        labels: xLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Rating',
            data: chartData,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#00B4CC',
          },
        ],
      },
      chartItSeason: {
        labels: xLabelsSeason,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Rating',
            data: chartDataSeason,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#00B4CC',
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    chartDataSeason = [];
    xLabelsSeason = [];
    let seasonNum = e.target.value.slice(6)
    console.log(seasonNum);

    for (let i = 0; i < allEpsData[seasonNum-1].length; i++){
      chartDataSeason.push(allEpsData[seasonNum-1][i].imdbRating);
      xLabelsSeason.push(`s${seasonNum}e${allEpsData[seasonNum-1][i].Episode} "${allEpsData[seasonNum-1][i].Title}"`)
    }

    this.setState({
      selectValue: e.target.value,
      seasonSelected: true,
    });

    // console.log(chartDataSeason)

  }
  render() {
    let seasons = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allEpsData.length; i++) {
      seasons.push(i);
    }

    if (this.state.seasonSelected === false) {
      return (
        <div>
          <select // selector
            className="select" 
            value={this.state.selectValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option>All Seasons</option>
            {seasons.map((el) => {
              return <option key={el}>season {el+1}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
          <div className="line-container">
            <Line
              data={this.state.chartIt}
              width={600}
              height={400}
              options={{
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      ticks: {
                        display: false, //this will remove only the label
                      },
                      gridLines: {
                        show: false,
                        display: false,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      gridLines: {
                        show: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                animation: {
                  duration: 200,
                  easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                },
                tooltips: {
                  enabled: true,
                },
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="seasons-graph-container"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>
          <select
            className="select"
            value={this.state.selectValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option>All Seasons</option>
            {seasons.map((el) => {
              return <option key={el}>season {el+1}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
          <div className="line-container">
            <Line
              data={this.state.chartItSeason}
              width={600}
              height={400}
              options={{
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      ticks: {
                        display: false, //this will remove only the label
                      },
                      gridLines: {
                        show: false,
                        display: false,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      gridLines: {
                        show: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                animation: {
                  duration: 200,
                  easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                },
                tooltips: {
                  enabled: true,
                },
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="seasons-graph-container"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

So right now, `chartIt` displays a graph and that works fine. However in the `handleChange(e)` method, I am trying to reset the data the Chart.js calls from by first setting `chartDataSeason = []`; and then `xLabelsSeason = [];`.

I am able to console.log the data and it is all there, I am unable to get it to render in a new Line chart though.

Any help would be appreciated. Also any tips on better organizing my code would be helpful, I am pretty new to React and I realize there is probably a better way to do all of this.

Answer (score 0):

When `setState` is called inside `handleChange` it will tell React to re-render the `Graph` component. There are some special cases where this would not happen (`PureComponent` or others) but as this is a plain component, it should call the `render` function. You can add a `console.log` there to confirm it.

However, even if `render` method is called, that doesn't mean that all the children components will be re-render too. React has a smart way to detect if a component in the tree needs to update or not, and it will only do it when necessary for performance reasons.

For this case in particular, there are a few options you can try:

- The `this.state.chartItSeason` is the actual data passed to the `Line` component, and the one which should be updated. Because the component is updating nested properties, React is probably not detecting it like a prop change. Try to replace the object reference, for example, inside of `handleChange`:

```
this.setState({
  selectValue: e.target.value,
  seasonSelected: true,
  chartItSeason: {
     ...this.state.chartItSeason
  }
});
```

This will create a new object which Chart.js may consider as a new data when comparing if the props have changed.

- You can always pass a `key` prop to any component that whenever it changes it will force the complete re-render of that component. That is almost always not the best approach and it should be avoided. You can read more about the use case for `key` in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)
- Also, as a side note, the two top-level variables `chartDataSeason` and `xLabelsSeason` should probably be better moved to the state or as instance properties (e.g. `this.chartDataSeason`) to allow more than one component to be rendered at the same time